# Timestamp in Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I prefer to use the **timestamp** as one of the column in Cassandra (which I decided to use as Clustering Key). which is the right way to store the column as timestamp in Cassandra?

(**i.e**) Is it fine to use the 'milliseconds' (Example : 1513078338560) directly like below?

```
INSERT INTO testdata (nodeIp, totalCapacity, physicalUsage, readIOPS, readBW, writeIOPS, writeBW, writeLatency, flashMode, timestamp) VALUES('172.30.56.60',1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,'yes',1513078338560);
```

or to use the dateof(now());

```
INSERT INTO testdata (nodeIp, totalCapacity, physicalUsage, readIOPS, readBW, writeIOPS, writeBW, writeLatency, flashMode, timestamp) VALUES('172.30.56.60',1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,'yes',dateof(now()));
```

which is faster and recommended way to use for timestamp based queries in Cassandra?

NOTE : I know internally it stores as milliseconds, I used the `'SELECT timestamp, blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob(timestamp)) FROM'`

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dateof` is deprecated in Cassandra >= 2.2... Instead it's better to use function `toTimestamp`, like this: `toTimestamp(now())`.  When you selecting, you can also use the `toUnixTimestamp` function if you want to get the timestamp as long:

```
cqlsh:test> CREATE TABLE test_times (a int, b timestamp, PRIMARY KEY (a,b));
cqlsh:test> INSERT INTO test_times (a,b) VALUES (1, toTimestamp(now()));
cqlsh:test> SELECT toUnixTimestamp(b) FROM test_times;

 system.tounixtimestamp(b)
---------------------------
         1513086032267

(1 rows)

cqlsh:test> SELECT b FROM test_times;

 b
---------------------------------
 2017-12-12 13:40:32.267000+0000

(1 rows)
```

Regarding the performance - there are different considerations:

1. If you already have the timestamp as number, then you can use it instead of calling function
2. It's better to use prepared statements instead of "raw inserts" - in this case Cassandra won't need to transfer full query, but only data, and also don't need to parse statement every time.

The pseudo code will look as following (Java-like).

```
PreparedStatement prepared = session.prepare(
    "insert into your_table (field1, field2) values (?, ?)");
while(true) {
    session.execute(prepared.bind(value1, value2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got your point of using toUnixTimestamp but I didn't get the second point completely, Could you please brief?

Comment: Also, Could you clarify the disadvantage of inserting timestamp like this '2017-12-12 13:40:32.267000+0000' instead of millisecond / toUnitTimestamp format?

Comment: I don't think that it should be significant disadvantage - it depends on your code.

Comment: I accepted your answer, my question is 'As a default 'timestamp' is storing the value as millisecond' so Is it better to use the timestamp in millisecond format (or) will there be a performance hiccups in using the timestamp as '2017-12-12 13:40:32.267000+0000'

Comment: I mean inserting as 'INSERT INTO test (nodeIp, totalCapacity, physicalUsage, readIOPS, readBW, writeIOPS, writeBW, writeLatency, flashMode, timestamp) VALUES('172.30.56.64',1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,'yes',2017-12-12 13:40:32.267000+0000);'

Comment: Or Is it better to insert like 'INSERT INTO nodedata (nodeIp, totalCapacity, physicalUsage, readIOPS, readBW, writeIOPS, writeBW, writeLatency, flashMode, timestamp) VALUES('172.30.56.64',1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,'yes',toTimestamp(now()));'

Comment: if the data is sent as string, then it could be slightly higher overhead for transferring & parsing this string. Regarding the 2nd - call to function may lead to some overhead, so I, personally will prefer sending either of number, or string.  But this really depends on the amount of inserts - if it's not 10th of thousands, then, I think, that use of function is ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161034/discussion-between-harry-and-alex-ott).